# How to limit Java String creation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

We are trying to improve performance in our Java application.  While using the Memory Analysis tool, I noticed that there are many duplicate Strings that seem to have originated in Hibernate.  For example, the Memory Analysis Tool sees over 6000 occurrences of "rowid_0_" and "0_", and tracing to the GC root shows Hibernate's involvement:

[image]

It seems as though we could improve performance if we could intern those Strings.  If it were "our" code, I could modify it and see the effects.  Is there any way that I can coerce Hibernate into using interned Strings?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? I don't see any `new String()` in `org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases`. If anything it does intern strings. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/3.3.1/org/hibernate/loader/DefaultEntityAliases.java

Comment: @Steve Kuo - We are using hibernate-core 3.6.10.Final and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.  Could it be a JPA thing?

Comment: @Steve Kuo - On line 87 of the link you provided, I see "rowIdAlias = Loadable.ROWID_ALIAS + suffix;".  This may be a culprit.

Comment: Yup I see it now, and `StringBuilder` does indeed create a new String.

Comment: Is 6000 extra string objects that big a deal?

Comment: @Steve Kuo - Regarding the 6000 Strings...  it may or may not be a big deal.  When I test a single user locally for our web app, it's not.  However, in production, we have many thousands of users, and we've seen excessive garbage collection.  There are many other duplicated Strings, some large and some small, some with many copies, and some with fewer.  My real question may be a general question about how to limit memory consumption in used libraries; however, those sorts of general questions seem to be frowned upon on StackOverflow.

Comment: Just to respond to the "big deal" comment. I have this problem in an application and 390mb of string size in there... due to hibernate. And I can't upgrade the version! #fml

Answer (score 1):

I now see that the Hibernate issue 3924 refers to this.  However, [HHH-3924](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3924) has a status of "Open", and is unresolved.  It does refer to a code patch that interns the rowid Strings.